# Submit a Form when any of the link or button on the page is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple links in a page and multiple buttons. These buttons are links are created dynamically. I can not have onclick event on each of these.

I want to submit a form objects to the next page when any of the link or button in the page is clicked.

HTML :

```
<a href="a.php"> 1 </a>
<a href="b.php"> 2 </a>
<input type="button" onclick="window.location('c.php')">
<form action="a.html" method="GET"> <input type="submit" value="d.php" /> </form>
....
<form action="#" name="frm1" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="i1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="i2" value="2">
....
....
</form>
```

In above example,

> I want to POST frm1 objects to the links (a.php or b.php or or c.php
>   or d.php) when corresponding link is clicked.

**Note**: OR , is it possible to submit a form a on current page link change instead of checking  each link is clicked or not.. something like, `onload` function in body. is there `on exit` function?

Comment: Look into [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: Please Explain what exactly you want to submit

Comment: @PrestonS : will it work on any browser ?

Comment: @Moussawi7 : I want to submit the frm1 objects to any pages of my website.

Comment: @PrestonS : i tried a sample of `onbeforeunload` its not working on click. `<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  alert ('Dialog text here.');
};
</script>
<a href="new.html">aaa</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of event bubbling.  Add an onclick handler to the body with the code to change and submit your form, then return false to cancel the original event.

```
<body onclick="document.forms.frm1.submit(); return false;">
    <a href="a.php">Go TO a.php</a>
    <a href="b.php">Go TO b.php</a>
    <input type="button" onclick="window.location('c.php')" value="c.php" />
</body>
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS2jp/1/)

Comment: this even works for non page redirect options.. for eg: `<input type="button"/>`

Comment: what is the function `form.submit();` doing ?

Comment: @logan, It was just a stub for whatever code you will use to submit your form.  Updated to correct syntax.

Comment: its not working if there is any form submit button. say `<form action="a.html" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" value="c.php" />
 </form>` it only works for onclick event

Comment: @logan, You didn't specify that as a requirement.  Re-visit your question and include all the requirements and code to get an answer that works for you.

Comment: I have already said, when a link or button is clicked... button includes onclick and submit... anyhow i updated my question with additional form button